# what css styles are analyzed by search engines?

Tags: web-development, seo, search-engines

I know that Google used to do things like look at `font-size` and `font-weight` (or the equivalents from when Google first started) from their initial paper. But that was in the 90's.

Does anybody know which styles are important to search engines now?

---

(Explanation: I know that technically we should serve up the same page to everyone—however, for many websites this simply isn't possible. A website I'm currently working on has a "content-only" version for search engines and users without JavaScript—they *cannot* integrate this version with the "main" JavaScript-friendly version of their site—and I'm not sure which styles I should carry over from the main site's content.)

Comment: To which Stack Exchange site should this question go if it's off topic?

Comment: does css matter at all?

Comment: As I said, Google (at least when it started) judged text importance by taking into account relative sizes and bolding of text.

Comment: That was 10(?) years ago.. use `<h1>` `<h2>` etc..

Comment: @luxun: I think it would be suitable for webmasters.SE, as it's a broad issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None. AFAIK CSS doesn't factor into it at all.

Update: I've asked Gary Illyes, who works for Google and he says:

> CSS files aren't indexed and as far as I know they're only fetched and used in very limited case

https://plus.google.com/109139237014771009015/posts/R5TCdFR19M8

Comment: As I said, Google (at least when it started) judged text importance by taking into account relative sizes and bolding of text.

Comment: That's right. Not any more. It's all about h1, h2, h3 tags for importance now.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: No, but CSS is notable by its absence in http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769 and http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35291 . External CSS is downloaded, as Matt Cutts mentions that hiding text via CSS is detected, but I am pretty sure it doesn't affect ranking in any other way. (So, unsourced, but I've seen no evidence to suggest otherwise)

Comment: So do you think I should just eliminate all CSS entirely?

Comment: Surely you want to provide a version of users without JS enabled anyway? If impossible, then yeah, I'd drop all CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As far i know, googles crawler doesn't like hidden text. E.g. when the background match text color.

Comment: does this mean that google will analyse css?